# How can I fix my code to be able to run all three methods?

Tags: java

I'm extremely new to Java (started less than a week ago) and need some help for Computer Science A. I've tried various things such as searching up the errors i'm receiving but it has been to no avail.

```
public class Geometry
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GeometryHelper solver1 = new GeometryHelper(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
        GeometryHelper solver2 = new GeometryHelper(3, 4);
        System.out.println("Distance between (2,5) and (6,7): " + distance);
        System.out.println("Slope of a line with two points (2,5) and (6,7): " + slope);
        System.out.println("Hypotenuse of a right triangle with sides 3 and 4: " + pythagoras);
    }
}

public class GeometryHelper
{
    public int x1;
    public int x2;
    public int y1;
    public int y2;
    public int a;
    public int b;
    public int c;
public double distance(double xl, double x2, double y1, double y2);
{
    double x = Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
    double y = Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2);
    double dist = (Math.sqrt(x+y));
    return dist;
}
public double slope(double xl, double x2, double y1, double y2);
{
    ansslope = (double)((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
    return ansslope;
}
public double pythagoras(double a, double b);
{
    hypotenus = (Math.sqrt((a*a) + (b*b)));
    return hypotenus;
}
}
```

Errors:

```
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/Geometry.java:7: error: constructor GeometryHelper in class GeometryHelper cannot be applied to given types;
        GeometryHelper solver1 = new GeometryHelper(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);
                                 ^
  required: no arguments
  found:    double,double,double,double
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/Geometry.java:8: error: constructor GeometryHelper in class GeometryHelper cannot be applied to given types;
        GeometryHelper solver2 = new GeometryHelper(3, 4);
                                 ^
  required: no arguments
  found:    int,int
  reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/Geometry.java:9: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("Distance between (2,5) and (6,7): " + distance);
                                                                  ^
  symbol:   variable distance
  location: class Geometry
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/Geometry.java:10: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("Slope of a line with two points (2,5) and (6,7): " + slope);
                                                                                 ^
  symbol:   variable slope
  location: class Geometry
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/Geometry.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
        System.out.println("Hypotenuse of a right triangle with sides 3 and 4: " + pythagoras);
                                                                                   ^
  symbol:   variable pythagoras
  location: class Geometry
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/GeometryHelper.java:11: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
public double distance(double xl, double x2, double y1, double y2);
              ^
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/GeometryHelper.java:16: error: return outside method
    return dist;
    ^
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/GeometryHelper.java:18: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
public double slope(double xl, double x2, double y1, double y2);
              ^
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/GeometryHelper.java:20: error: cannot find symbol
    ansslope = (double)((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
    ^
  symbol:   variable ansslope
  location: class GeometryHelper
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/GeometryHelper.java:21: error: return outside method
    return ansslope;
    ^
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/GeometryHelper.java:23: error: missing method body, or declare abstract
public double pythagoras(double a, double b);
              ^
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/GeometryHelper.java:25: error: cannot find symbol
    hypotenus = (Math.sqrt((a*a) + (b*b)));
    ^
  symbol:   variable hypotenus
  location: class GeometryHelper
/tmp/compilejava-fPdFIa/GeometryHelper.java:26: error: return outside method
    return hypotenus;
    ^
13 errors`
```

Comment: Please include the errors you’re receiving.

Comment: Your constructor is missing.

Comment: What is `c` for?

Comment: You need to either define `static` methods or learn to define classes in object-oriented programming. Study some basic tutorials before posting here. Oracle provides extensive tutorials at no cost.

Comment: Your code contains a lot of compilation errors.  Your first step would be to fix the compilation of the GeometryHelper class.

Answer (score 1):

- constructor is missing in `GeometryHelper` class
- `;` should not there in end of methods
- if you want to use the methods of the classes, it should be like

this : `solver.distance() , solver.slope() , etc`
where `GeometryHelper solver = new GeometryHelper();`

I have debugged the code, hope below code helps you
if there is doubt, you are free to ask

```java
import java.util.*;

class GeometryHelper
{

    public double distance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
    {
        double x = Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2);
        double y = Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2);
        double dist = (Math.sqrt(x+y));
        return dist;
    }
    public double slope(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2)
    {
        double ansslope = (double)((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
        return ansslope;
    }
    public double pythagoras(double a, double b)
    {
        double  hypotenus = (Math.sqrt((a*a) + (b*b)));
        return hypotenus;
    }
}

public class Geometry
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        GeometryHelper solver = new GeometryHelper();
        System.out.println("Distance between (2,5) and (6,7): " + solver.distance(2,5,6,7));
        System.out.println("Slope of a line with two points (2,5) and (6,7): " + solver.slope(2,5,6,7));
        System.out.println("Hypotenuse of a right triangle with sides 3 and 4: " + solver.pythagoras(3,4));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`new GeometryHelper(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0);`

Here you are trying to call a constructor which accepts 4 `double` arguments.
But you do not have that constructor in `GeometryHelper` class.

`distance(double xl, double x2, double y1, double y2)` is a method not a constructor.`

To call this method, you will need an object of `GeometryHelper`,

You can refer the below code.

```
 public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        GeometryHelper solver1 = new GeometryHelper();

        System.out.println("Distance between (2,5) and (6,7): " + solver1.distance(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0));
        System.out.println("Slope of a line with two points (2,5) and (6,7): " + solver1.slope(2.0, 6.0, 5.0, 7.0));
        System.out.println("Hypotenuse of a right triangle with sides 3 and 4: " + solver1.pythagoras(3, 4));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

GeometryHelper would be better as a class with static methods that perform various computation. This way you won't need to create an object each time you have to compute the distance of two points.

Below is the code that you are probably looking for.

```
class GeometryHelper {
   static double distance(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2){
      return (Math.sqrt(Math.pow(x2 - x1, 2)+Math.pow(y2 - y1, 2)));
   }
   static double slope(double x1, double x2, double y1, double y2){
      return(double)((y2-y1)/(x2-x1));
   }
   static double pythagoras(double a, double b){
      return (Math.sqrt((a*a) + (b*b)));
   }
}

public class Main{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println("Distance between (2,5) and (6,7): " + 
                           GeometryHelper.distance(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0));
        System.out.println("Slope of a line with two points (2,5) and (6,7): " + 
                          GeometryHelper.slope(1.0, 2.0, 3.0, 4.0));
        System.out.println("Hypotenuse of a right triangle with sides 3 and 4: " + 
                         GeometryHelper.pythagoras(3, 4));
    }
}
```